# Selecting one element from set only by CSS selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a table:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1</td>
        <td>col 2</td>
        <td>col 3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1</td>
        <td class="editable">value 1</td>
        <td class="editable">value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2</td>
        <td class="editable">value 1</td>
        <td class="editable">value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 3</td>
        <td class="editable">value 1</td>
        <td class="editable">value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 4</td>
        <td class="editable">value 1</td>
        <td class="editable">value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 5</td>
        <td class="editable">value 1</td>
        <td class="editable">value 2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I select (using only CSS selectors) only one element from `td.editable`? Analog of jQuery `:first` selector will be acceptable.

Comment: Only first element. querySelector("td.editable:first")

Comment: `querySelector('td.editable')` will return you the first element, but that's because `querySelector()` always limits selections to the first match. If you use `querySelectorAll('td.editable')` it will return all of them, which isn't what you want, unless you're specifically using that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an n-th child selector. Use one to get at the exact table row that you want, then use a second n-th child to get at the exact `<td>` element you want.
For example if I wanted the second row, and the second `<td>` element with a class="editable" I could do this:

```
tr:nth-child(2) > td.editable:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

On compatible browsers, you can use [the :nth-child pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anth-child)

Comment: cssSelector("td.editable:nth-child(1)") will return set of first "editable" td elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your only table of td.editable's?  Try something like this...

```
td.editable:nth-child(2) //or 3 or 4, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is what you want but try this:

```
table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXbT5/)**